# ATMEGA32 Jtag flash

Tags: atmega, jtag, flash, parallel

Can you recommend an inexpensive product for flashing an in circuit (read: powered) ATMEGA32 via JTAG.

I have a parallel port available on my laptop dock/port replicator, which I am guessing may be the cheapest form of these. I intend to use PonyProg to flash the ATMEGA32. I do not need the capability to debug in line, but simply to load someone else's off the shelf program (monome firmware) to the ATMEGA32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Lady Ada's USBtinyISP](http://learn.adafruit.com/usbtinyisp) with [avrdude](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/).  The [kit](http://www.adafruit.com/products/46) cost $22 and supports both the 6-pin and 10-pin interfaces.  You can learn a lot more about making [AVR target boards](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/article.php/avrtargetboards) courtesy of the [Evil Mad Scientist(s)](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/).  I also found an Instructable for a [truly bare-bones parallel port programmer](http://www.instructables.com/id/Ghetto-Programming%3a-Getting-started-with-AVR-micro/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need a JTAG programmer?
On most AVRs are two methods available to program the flash.

- Isp Programming
- Jtag Programming
  Isp programmer are cheaper, but JTAG supports debugging
  For Jtag are mainly two Programmer available: Dragon and JTAGice mkii